# Triggering events in real-time from an Audio-Unit render callback and getting severe distortion

Tags: objective-c, c, audio, real-time, core-audio

I am creating a light weight sequencer based around the `AUSampler`audio unit.  Essentially, on each "tick" I want to perform some actions.  The core technique here is exploiting the audio units rendering callbacks for their real-time precision callbacks and invoking further functionality to be arbitrarily defined.  Based on this particular callback:

```
static OSStatus renderCallback (void                        *inRefCon,
                                AudioUnitRenderActionFlags  *ioActionFlags,
                                const AudioTimeStamp        *inTimeStamp,
                                UInt32                      inBusNumber,
                                UInt32                      inNumberFrames,
                                AudioBufferList             *ioData){



   SuperTimer *_superTimer   = (__bridge SuperTimer*)inRefCon;

   _superTimer->samplesSinceLastCall += inNumberFrames;

   if (_superTimer->samplesSinceLastCall > 10000) {

      _superTimer->tickMethod();
      _superTimer->samplesSinceLastCall = 0;
   }
   return 0;
}
```

This is a conventional render callback for a default output audio unit on `OSX`.   Eventually I should replace the hardcoded `10000` with a number that is relative to the current buffer size `inNumberFrame` but this serve to give me consistent invocations of `tickMethod()` which is a block defined as:

`void (^tickMethod)(void);`

At the sample-rate 44100kHZ (which the hardware seems to default to) and its buffer size of 512 frames I get whatever code I choose to definein the block invoked at something like twice a second.  (although i'm not too concerned with this value at the moment and can be fixed with relative valued logic inside the render function i imagine).

In main, I instantiate the object that handles the audio-unit initialization and rendering and assign some code to the block in an initializer.

```
int main(int argc, const char * argv[]) {


    Dispatch * dispatch = [[Dispatch alloc] init];

   Sampler * sampler = [[Sampler alloc] init];

   SuperTimer * time = [[SuperTimer alloc] initWithCompletion:^{
      printf("test");
      [dispatch sequencer];
   }];

   CFRunLoopRunInMode(kCFRunLoopDefaultMode, 1000, false);
}
```

I ask the run loop to extend the life of my application and voila, i get "test" printed to the console in real time twice a second.  However, the `sequencer` method call immediately causes a grinding distortion sound that wakes up my neighbors.  Really awful and horrendous sound that comes out of the speakers brutally loud even at the minimum volume setting.

Therefore, my question is about how can I get essentially an "entry point" into Objective-C land without causing the audio system to cease up?  One thing is I need the sample hits to happen immediately but I also need to make data changes (like what beat count am I on, etc..).  Those things can happen not exactly in real-time but at least within the time-bounds of each callback.

So, I believe I need to break out of the real-time thread my callback is on and also return execution to its caller within the buffer rate constraints and perhaps continue my logic on another thread.  However, as a n00b at concurrent programming I am not quite sure how and even if I should try that approach.

Any comments or suggestions would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 0):

I don't find easy giving a fair and practical reply to your question without walking on the edge of Stackoverflow [good answering practice](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer). 
Although I'm sure that transmitting timing events has nothing to do with static noise (you have to silence the buffers, as shown in example code), I'm not sure if what you suggest is the best way of getting what you seemingly want to get. Although `CoreAudio` rendering timing is unique for its precision, please don't forget it is a ***callback***, not a ***call***. In other words, the system has all the timing information it needs, and calls the callback procedure whenever it needs, with real-time priority. All you have to provide is output data. 
However, this *real-time priority* is only guaranteed for the audio buffers, else you would have been hearing clicks and glitches. For user data which control the parameters of the render callback, but happen outside the real-time render thread this real time priority is far from being guaranteed. Only audio I/O has the real time priority, AFAIK. Yet, the callback itself is time based. In case you analyze this piece of code:

```
Boolean debug;

static OSStatus renderCallback ( void *inRefCon,
                       AudioUnitRenderActionFlags *ioActionFlags,
                       const AudioTimeStamp *inTimeStamp, //observe this!
                       UInt32 inBusNumber,
                       UInt32 inNumberFrames,
                       AudioBufferList *ioData )
{
  OSStatus lErr = noErr;
  static Float64 prev_stime;  //prev. sample time
  static UInt64  prev_htime;  //prev. host time  
  Float64 scycle = inTimeStamp->mHostTime   - prev_htime;
  Float64 hcycle = inTimeStamp->mHostTime   - prev_htime; 
  if(debug) //use *only* for printout debugging!
      printf("frames: %d\thcycle: %lld\tscycle: %7.2lf\n",
            (unsigned int)inNumberFrames,hcycle,scycle);
  prev_htime = inTimeStamp->mHostTime;
  prev_stime = inTimeStamp->mSampleTime;

  Float32 *lBuffer0 = (Float32 *)gAudioBufferList->mBuffers[0].mData;
  Float32 *lBuffer1 = (Float32 *)gAudioBufferList->mBuffers[1].mData;
  memset(lBuffer0,  0, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));
  memset(lBuffer1,  0, inNumberFrames*sizeof(Float32));   
  return lErr;
}
```

you'll see that you don't need samples in order to have precise timing information. All the timing variables can also be members of your `SuperTimer` controller struct in C (or interface in Obj-C), and this would be it. There is no guarantee at which precise moment of a render cycle your timing variables will get updated with new values and become visible to the rest of your program and its user. An educated guess is *at the end of the render cycle*. There's a CoreAudio API for [adjusting buffer length](https://developer.apple.com/library/mac/technotes/tn2321/_index.html#//apple_ref/doc/uid/DTS40013499-CH1-THE_I_O_BUFFER_SIZE), in your case, for minimum latency.
So, I guess it's worth doing it this way only if you need precise audio visual synchronization for your instrument. Please also consider other latencies, such as visualization latency, MIDI delay (if you use it) into "feasibility calculation" of your project. 
There is also a very instructive reading from CoreAudio developer Michael Tyson, dealing with timing issues, with [example code](http://atastypixel.com/blog/experiments-with-precise-timing-in-ios/) one can learn from. 
To conclude, please feel encouraged toward individual research.

### Update

One of the most important things: one should **never** use blocking functions or memory management (alloc, release, and other Obj-C "magic" such as `Sampler * sampler = [[Sampler alloc] init];`) on the real time thread - you open your code to the risks of [priority inversion](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Priority_inversion), which in audio means clicks, dropouts, distortion and likewise undefined behavior [here's one example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/36615010/experiencing-audio-dropouts-with-os-x-core-audio-playback-output)! CA callbacks are written in plain-C for this reason!

Comment: you are correct in pointing out the distortion issue (which came from the uninitialized audio buffers from memory garbage) is a separate question.  with regards, to the basis of a sequencer, I have found that running logic in the render callback that calls an external function every (x % n == 0) where n determines how many times the external function is not invoked.  From there I can have some degree of granularity of control for the base "clock" of my sequencer. ideally, the buffer frame sizes ought to be very low to make this approach more accurate and fine tunable

Comment: i will continue to read through your post if perhaps i did not get the full thrust.  i will have to play around with host timing and observe the time stamps to test how these real time render callbacks interoperate with the rest of program execution.  i believe you made the point that this callback is not time precise in and of itself?  or that external functions called from it are themselves not guaranteed to be "realtime".  regardless, using the approach i outlined in the first comment gets me really good sounding quantization on my sequencer and blows NSTimer out of the water.

Comment: the callback is as precise in itself as system calls toward it are precise, which applies to the **audio buffers** - and is _real time_. I wouldn't bet on "tricking the system" into "thinking" that external functions called from it are themselves not guaranteed to be "realtime". It is a callback and external functions are not its child processes. Please, also note that `inTimeStamp` variable from the callback has nothing to do with `NSTimer API`. This is plain-C. Best bet would be to study some of M. Tyson's example code about timing. Hope this answer satisfies.

Comment: i will have to read this article and re read what you've said as i'm not that knowledgeable on system level timing nor the details of function execution.  however, for what it is worth, my current code does provide a basis for a sequencer component i've written of which the resultant drum beats sound perfectly on beat.

Comment: Please be prepared for a steep learning curve and a lot of individual research.

Comment: i read the learning core audio book and went through all the exercises and have an app on in the appstore that utilizes audio units.  so i'm aware of this alleged learning curve.  with all that behind me, i still feel like i'm at the foot of a very large mountain when it comes to CA

Comment: Also be aware that "Learning CA" as well as much of Apple example code overencourages using the `AUGraph API` even for simplest tasks, where it's not needed. One such example is CH07_AUGraphSineWave. Make sure to study it _thoroughly_. It is misguiding in this sense, yet great to learn from...

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/110856/discussion-between-user5797668-and-user3078414).